# Prevent ajax submit with blank inputs and selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm stuck on here:

```
//Saving Data
    $('#saveButton').click(function(){

        var teamA = $('#teamA').val();
        var teamB = $('#teamB').val();
        var date = $('#date').val();
        var timeOfEvent = $('#timeOfEvent').val();
        var live = "0";
        if($("#live").is(':checked'))
            live = $('#live').val();

        $.ajax({
            url  : "ajax.php",
            type : "POST",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data :
            {
                'submitAddEvents' : 1,
                'teamA' : teamA,
                'teamB' : teamB,
                'date' : date,
                'timeOfEvent' : timeOfEvent,
                'live' : live,
            },
            success:function(data)
            {

                if(!data.success) {
                    alert(data.message);
                }else{
                    window.location = "addEvents.php";
                }

            }
        });
    });
```

That's what I already have.. It's "everything" ok BUT even with `required` in `inputs` and `selects` when I click on button It inserts the data into the database without prevent the blank inputs or selects...

**WHAT I ALREADY DID**
I put a `<form>` and I changed my ajax

```
$('#saveButton').click(function(){
```

to

```
$('#saveButton').submit(function(ev){
ev.preventDefault();
```

And didn't work.. In this case It blocks the empty inputs but when I fill the inputs and click on button nothing happens..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must select your form, not your button to attach submit listener, instead of this:

```
$('#saveButton').submit(function(ev){
ev.preventDefault();
```

change to:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(ev){
ev.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, instead of using 
`.val()` to each input that you have, you can just use `var data = $("#myform").serialize();` and you will have all the submitted inputs inside the form, you  can do a `console.log(data);` and you will see the results there.

Another thing is: If you want to validate the data you need to register the form submit, not the button click, so, instead of using `$("#savebutton").click(function(){});` use `$("#myform").on('submit', function(){});` and to all your html inputs should be like this:

```
<input type="text" name="stack" placeholder="Name" required>
```

And its going to work.